# violation of const variable using a pointer c++

Tags: c++

Why i am allowed to change a const value without errors?

```
void foo(long * a)
{
    *a = 50;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const long a = 7; 
    const long * b = &a;

    foo((long *)b);
    // now the value of a is 50
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading up about logical vs. bitwise `const`ness. You *can* do what you just did, but you shouldn't because it violates the logical `const`ness of the variable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's fair, but I see that **a lot** and this is the first time I've seen anybody called out for it. I guess I'll feel special.

Comment: @Barry: I see it a lot too. More and more lately. It's a shame. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're *not*.**

When you wrote that C-style cast, you disabled the checks. If you'd written this:

```
foo(static_cast<long*>(b));
```

or just

```
foo(b);
```

then your program would not have compiled.

In order to allow you to do expert magic, you can still write:

```
foo(const_cast<long*>(b));
```

but then it's still *your* responsibility to ensure that you do not use it for evil, such as the evil in your example.

Answer (score 4):

Because you casted the constness away with the cast `(long*)`. Your program engenders undefined behavior as you attempt to modify a `const` object.

Especially when casting pointers you should rely on the C++-Casts (`static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`), which do not implicitly cast away constness as the C-style cast does. That can only be done explicitly using `const_cast`, which is almost exclusively used for APIs with lacking const-correctness (and some hacks).
If you try to pass the argument without the cast (which is the way that arguments should usually be passed to functions):

```
foo(b);
```

You will get [an appropriate error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e9898ba3331df9b).

Comment: giggle you said "gender"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh lol you're right (I can't bloody wait for the 13. :o))